# Vuex getter not reactive when inside module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a getter inside a Vuex module. I change the value with a mutator and the state property changes, but the getter property is still the same, it doesn't react.

Then when I try to move the getter to the main Vuex store, it is reactive and works.
I don't know why the module isn't reactive?

Here is Vuex store:

```
import {mymodule} from './vuex-modules' 
  
export default new Vuex.Store({ 
    modules: {  mymodule }, 
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        updateState(state, payload) { 
            this.state[payload.stateName] = payload.newValue;
        },
    }, 
})
```

And the module:

```
export const mymodule = { 
    state: {  
        myproperty: ['defaultvalue']              //<-- the property is in the module's state
    },
    getters: {  
        myproperty: state => state.myproperty      //<-- getting myproperty from local state
    }, 
}
```

In the component I have a computed property with mapGetters:

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters({ 
         myproperty: 'myproperty'
    }),
```

I make a commit from the component (calls `updateState` in mutations):

```
 let object = { stateName: 'myproperty', newValue:'newelement' }  
 this.$store.commit('updateState', object);
```

The Vuex state changes, but the computed property is unchanged.

I can simply move the getter from the module into the Vuex store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({

    modules: { mymodule }, 
    getters: {
        myproperty: state => state.myproperty
    },
```

Now it works, the computed property `myproperty` has 'newelement' instead.
What can be the problem?

**UPDATE**

So I can't use  `this.state[payload.stateName]` inside the mutation, I have to specify which module it lies in. But how can I make it dynamic then?
I thought it was like mixins where it was merged together.

Is there a way to target a state property in a mutator without having to specify the module it may be in?

Otherwise I can't have a mutator that is common for both the main state and modules.

Answer (score 1):

I have now understood that the mutator didn't access the module's property, it was only accessing its own state properties. So it was adding a new property to the main state while the target property was inside the module.

So this:

```
mutations: {
 updateState(state, payload) {
            
      state[payload.stateName] = payload.newValue;
 },
```

Should be:

```
state.mymodule[payload.stateName] = payload.newValue;
```

So this is why it happened I guess. But I have something to add in an edit to the question.